# How to pass on to parent only props that its children accept?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm implementing with **React** + **Typescript** an architecture that's personally called *forward*. What it does is simply pass on all the props it receives to its children.

However,  I want to allow only props compatible with its children, not any property. For example, if there's `<input>` children, I want to allow only `<input>` properties.

See my try:

```
type ForwardProps<P> = Partial<P> & {
    children?: React.ReactElement<P>;
}

export function Forward<P> ({ children, ...props }: ForwardProps<P>) {
    const mapped = React.Children.map(children, child => {
        if (React.isValidElement<P>(child)) {
            return React.cloneElement<P>(child, props);
        }

        return child;
    });

    return <>{ mapped }</>;
}

<Forward className="good-input">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
</Forward>
```

When I try to get `...props`, Typescript says "Rest types may only be created from object types".

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want in the only allowing props that the component takes, but about the typescript error you could add props as an optional any property like this:

```
type ForwardProps<P> = Partial<P> & {
    children?: React.ReactElement<P>;
    props?: any
}

export function Forward<P> ({ children, props }: ForwardProps<P>) {
    const mapped = React.Children.map(children, child => {
        if (React.isValidElement<P>(child)) {
            return React.cloneElement<P>(child, props);
        }

        return child;
    });

    return <>{ mapped }</>;
}

<Forward className="good-input">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
</Forward>
```